# move a whole featuregroup around (with all rectangles drawn) on the page map in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using leaflet.draw to draw rectangles on an image/map, as seen in the link below:

http://leafletjs.com/2013/02/20/guest-post-draw.html

I am able to use the edit button to move individual ones around. I am wanting to select all the rectangles on the page and move them all together at the same time.

I have looked at other plugins written to move polygons, but none move all of the shapes together at the same time.

Any suggestions?